# High rate of InternalServerError when sending FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We're receiving what seems to be an unreasonably high rate of Error 500 (Internal Server Error) when sending via FCM.

Some points :

- We use both the FCM legacy HTTP API as well as HTTP v1 API, both return an error around 3% of requests sent.
- We have implemented exponential backoff way more than is required (the first error we stop sending for 30 seconds, and increment up to 5 minutes).
- There is no "Retry-After" returned to us.
- We are removing any tokens that are returned as unregistered.
- We send over 500k messages per day. I'm sure by Google volume this is negligible.
- We have tried using batch sending using the endpoint - https://fcm.googleapis.com/batch this also returns the same error percentage and often higher.
- Have sent to Firebase support but (as usual) do not expect anything useful from them.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I see the same issue today. Did you get this resolve?

Comment: I opened a ticket with GCP support and they resolved it.